# How should I remove Bahiagrass from Blue Couch lawn? (Digitaria didactyla, crab grass)

Tags: weed-control, weeds, lawn

Now it's warming up substantially in Queensland, my Bahiagrass infestation is becoming apparent. Any tips from removing this from [my](http://thelawnguide.com.au/lawn-varieties/35-lawn-varieties/139-queensland-blue-grass.html) [lawn](http://thelawnguide.com.au/lawn-varieties/35-lawn-varieties/139-queensland-blue-grass.html)?

It's quite long in sections so I have been able to isolate these sections and spray them with glyphosate but obviously this won't work in the short sections as it will also kill my turf.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, They are both warm season perennials, and as such will be similarly affected by any treatment from selective herbicides. The only reliable method of removal will take out your lawn as well (tarping or herbicide). Once it's dead, you can prevent germination for the most part with a pre em. And if you do see a small clump shoot up, you can take care of it while small.

Comment: I resorted to letting it grow out much longer than the underlying turf and then applying roundup gel to the leaves. Quite effective with about 50% removal with each application. Unfortunately this gel is very expensive so I'm trying different methods of mixing my own using liquids such as vegetable glycerin. I was going to use gelatin powder but I think cheap hair gel will do the trick!